# Memory leak when filtering with Core image

Tags: ios, xcode, core-image

So I've been using core image to apply filters on images, everything is good except when I try to apply the same filter over and over again the application just quits, I guess its a memory leak.

Here's the code:

```
-(UIImage *) applyFilter: (UIImage*) picture
{

    UIImageOrientation originalOrientation = picture.imageOrientation;
    CGFloat originalScale = picture.scale;   


    CIImage *beginImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:picture.CGImage];  


    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];

    CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CISepiaTone" 
                                  keysAndValues: kCIInputImageKey, beginImage, 
                        @"inputIntensity", [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.8], nil];

    CIImage *outputImage = [filter outputImage];

    CGImageRef cgimg = 
    [context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:[outputImage extent]];
    UIImage *newImg = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg scale:originalScale orientation:originalOrientation];

    beginImage = nil;
    context = nil;
    filter = nil;
    outputImage = nil;
    cgimg = nil;
    [beginImage release];
    [context release];
    [filter release];
    [outputImage release];
    //CGImageRelease(CGImageRef) method.
    CGImageRelease(cgimg);

    return newImg;
}
```

And to filter I simply do

```
UIImage *ima = [self.filter applyFilter:self.imageView.image];
imageView.image = ima ;
```

The applyFilter is a method of Filter class that I created

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set variables to nil before you call `release`, so the `release` has no effect. But you should not release most of the stuff anyway. You only need to release objects that you **created** (I hope the following list is complete):

- Objective-C objects that were returned by methods starting with `alloc`, `init`, `copy`, `new`
- Foundation objects returned by Objective-C methods starting with `create`, or by functions containing `Create` or `Copy`.

Delete these lines and it should be fine:

```
beginImage = nil;
context = nil;
filter = nil;
outputImage = nil;
cgimg = nil;
[beginImage release];
[context release];
[filter release];
[outputImage release];
```

You need to keep the line `CGImageRelease(cgimg);` because the method used to get `cgimg` contains `create` – you create it, you release it.

Comment: Hi @Meenakshi, should you share the code that hasn't worked for you? Do you use ARC?

Comment: Hi, Yes I am using ARC and I have added the question, link is

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23628783/memory-leak-for-coreimage

Here I have added the code.

Comment: @Tammo Freese Can you please review code and plz tell me what should i done wrong in code?